# Équivalent de « cinéphile » pour le jeu vidéo

Tags: vocabulaire, demande-de-mot, synonymes

Je suis quelqu'un qu'on peut appeler un amateur de jeux vidéo. En plus de jouer pour me détendre, je suis aussi passionné par l'industrie du jeu vidéo, les personnes derrières etc.

Je cherchais l'autre jour un mot pour définir cette passion, et le plus proche que j'étais capable de trouver est « cinéphile » pour un amateur de films et de leur univers.

Il y as bien sur le terme « *gamer* », mais je préférerais un terme français, et ce terme est très orienté sur la consommation plus que la passion.

Existe-t-il un mot qui corresponde à ce terme pour un amateur de jeux vidéo ?

Comment: Le plus souvent c'est justement `amateur de jeux vidéo` qui est utilisé.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ce serait "ludophile" pour les jeux en général.
On voit parfois "vidéo-ludophile", mais ce n'est pas très heureux.

Comment: Infos suppl. : je l'ai retrouvé [ici](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=17558818) (voir [aussi](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=17486222)). Dans un registre plus familier, le part. passé _mordu_ substantivé, à la base d'un truc normalisé comme [_mordu](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=alt&__index=alt&codom2nd=&srchtxt=MORDU&comencsrch.x=0&comencsrch.y=0) de l'informatique_. Merci !

Comment: Amateur, mordu, passionné et leurs synonymes font l'affaire, mais c'est bon à savoir.